# Comparing table values with a variable SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to compare data from a table in SQL Server with a variable value, and I get the error

> Must declare the scalar variable @DataSearched

This is my query:

```
    DECLARE @DateSeached INT
    SET @DateSeached = '9'

    SELECT *
    FROM Tax2ComputationType as t
    INNER JOIN ComputationValue as c ON t.TaxId != c.ComputationTaxId
    WHERE t.ValidityStartDate BETWEEN c.ValidityStartDate AND c.ValidityEndDate
      AND t.ValidityEndDate > @DateSeached
```

I have also tried writing the code like this:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)
SET @sql = 'SELECT * .....' and so on
SET @sql = @sql + 'AND t.ValidityEndDate >' + @DateSearched
```

And I get the same  error. I searched for a time the answer and I couldn't find it. Can anyone help me?

Comment: MySQL <> SQL-Server

Comment: You named the variable `@DateSeached`, but your error is that it can't find `@DateSearched` (note the corrected misspelling).  Also, why are you declaring it an `INT` then quoting the value you're setting?  If it's an `INT`, don't use single quotes.

Comment: thnak you, the problem was at the quotes

Comment: I concur with the previous commentators. Also, everything sounds like it's a date: `@DataSearched`, `ValidityEndDate`, yet you compare/set it to `9`. What does this mean, what sort of data _is_ `ValidityEndDate`?

Comment: It is just a theoretical example where i replaced DateTime format with int for the simplicity of learning. All ValidityStartDate and ValidityEndDate of type int